# How to make a automatic scrolling textview in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, scroll

I have two textviews that one of them is fixed and another one will be bigger and bigger. So I want a scrollable textview. I have a scrollable textview but my main problem is that when textview scrolls I should myself scroll up it to see its contents. I want my textview scrolls itself. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
```

`android:scrollbars = "vertical"` this is the properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but I think it does not solve my problem. I want my textview scroll itself before I pull up the screen